# How can I match all the values that start with "dynamic_key" but extract and save the end "single_name" to an array?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a database value with multipie valuest.  Wha I want is parts like this one:

```
"dynamic_key";s:11:"single_name"
```

How can I match all the values that start with "dynamic_key" but extrect and save the end
"single_name" to an array?

For example:

> "save_to_database";b:0;s:21:"dynamic_default_value";b:1;s:11:"dynamic_key";s:2:"id";}i:1;a:
>   8:
>   {s:2:"id";i:36;s:4:"type";s:6:"hidden";s:5:"label";s:10:"user_login";s:13:"default_value";s:12:"{user_login}";s:9:"is_hidden";b:0;s:16:"save_to_database";b:0;s:21:"dynamic_default_value";b:0;s:11:"dynamic_key";s:0:"";}i:2;a:28:{s:2:"id";i:1;s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:5:"label";s:15:"שם
>   האומן";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:8:"required";b:0;s:13:"default_value";s:0:"";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:19:"clear_default_value";b:0;s:19:"reset_default_value";b:1;s:11:"admin_label";s:0:"";s:16:"required_message";s:0:"";s:9:"is_hidden";b:0;s:16:"save_to_database";b:0;s:15:"label_placement";s:7:"inherit";s:11:"label_width";s:0:"";s:12:"tooltip_type";s:7:"inherit";s:13:"tooltip_event";s:7:"inherit";s:18:"prevent_duplicates";b:0;s:23:"duplicate_found_message";s:0:"";s:5:"logic";b:0;s:12:"logic_action";s:4:"show";s:11:"logic_match";s:3:"all";s:11:"logic_rules";a:0:{}s:21:"dynamic_default_value";b:1;s:11:"dynamic_key";s:11:"artist_name";s:6:"styles";a:0:{}s:7:"filters";a:1:{i:0;a:4:

So if I run preg_match_all on this text I will have an array that holds: `id`, `artist_name`.

Comment: Why not just unserialize it?

Comment: Oh, dear Lord of Sarcasm

Comment: Gundars, did i miss something funny ?

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is serialized PHP data. You can unserialize it with the PHP function [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize) (big surprise).

Be careful with userdata though, since it is possible to execute malicious code during deserialization.

Comment: knittl, thank you. with a bit google on unserialize i succeded.